# Commutators in Gupta-Bleuler formalism for quantization of the electromagnetic field

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator, gauge

In the [Gupta-Bleuler formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gupta%E2%80%93Bleuler_formalism) we have for the canonical momenta

$$\pi_\mu=F_{\mu0}-g_{\mu0}\partial_\alpha A^\alpha. $$

Every resource I find online say that the equal time canonical commutation relations

$$[A_\mu(x),A_\nu(x')]=[\pi_\mu(x),\pi_\nu(x')]=0\\ [A_\mu(x),\pi_\nu(x')]=ig_{\mu\nu}\delta(x-x') $$

imply
$$ [\dot{A}_\mu(x),A_\nu(x')]=ig_{\mu\nu}\delta(x-x').$$

I don't see how this is the case. We have in general

$$[A_\mu(x),\pi_\nu(x')]= [A_\mu(x),F_{\nu0}(x')-g_{\nu0}\partial_\alpha A^\alpha(x')]=[A_\mu(x),\partial_\nu A_0(x')]-[A_\mu(x), \partial_0A_\nu(x')]-[A_\mu(x),\partial_\alpha A^\alpha(x')]g_{\nu0}.$$

The second term is the one we're looking for. I can't see why the other terms must cancel.

The first relation gives us, differentiating $$[A_\mu,A_\nu]=0\implies[\partial_\alpha A_\mu,A_\nu]=[\partial_\alpha A_\nu,A_\mu]$$

the second gives

$$ [F_{\mu0},F_{\nu 0}]=0\qquad[F_{\mu0},\partial_\nu A^\nu]=0.$$

These last relations are only between derivatives of the fields, and the previous one don't seem to help. I must be missing something huge because everyone takes this as obvious and I couldn't find any similar question on here.

Is there a reason I don't see why in general if two operators commute, they commute with their derivatives too? Or is that not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than you think. Suppose $A(x, t)$ and $B(x', t)$ commute for all $x$ and $x'$. To compute a commutator with a spatial derivative, just use the definition of the derivative,
$$[A(x), \partial_{x'} B(x')] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{[A(x), B(x' + \epsilon)] - [A(x), B(x')]}{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{0 - 0}{\epsilon} = 0.$$
This gets rid of most of the extra terms. The surviving terms involving temporal derivatives cancel between the first and third iterms.

Comment: But then isn't $[\partial_0 A_\mu(x), A_\nu(x')]=0$ by the same reasoning?

Comment: @user2723984 No, because the commutators only vanish at equal times. Commutators with _spatial_ derivatives are automatically zero, I suppressed the $t$ arguments. The time derivative terms cancel between the first and third terms.

Comment: @user2723984 Thanks for the accept -- if you have any further issues you may actually want to hold off on it, to attract answers from others.

Comment: Of course, thank you. It was truly easier than I thought, I spent way too much time fiddling around with commutators. For the moment I don't think I have other issues, but if you suggest it I'll hold off on the accept until I can award the bounty.